# Composing equal characteristic and mixed characteristic deformations

Tags: moduli-spaces, deformation-theory, characteristic-p

Suppose $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$ and $A$ is a $k$-point on a moduli space of certain objects over $k$. Suppose, moreover, that $A$ deforms to a $k[[t]]$-point $B$ and a $W(k)$-point $C$ (in characteristic $0$). I wonder if there is any literature discuss whether one can "compose" $B$ and $C$ to form a $W(k)[[t]]$-point $D$ that is a $p$-deformation of $B$ and a $t$-deformation of $C$?

I am interested in this question because I am trying to show a $W(k)$-point $C$ as above always has a property $P$ relative to $A$. We know that holds when $A$ verifies a condition $E$. Furthermore, a lift of $B$ to characteristic zero always satisfies $E$, hence having property $P$. Therefore, if we can find a composition of $B$ and $C$, then, as reduction preserves $P$, we are done.

Comment: Murphy's law(s) tell you that there exist many kinds of objects with quite arbitrary formal deformation spaces, in particular with ${\rm Def}_A \simeq \operatorname{Spf} W(k)[[t]]/(pt)$, which is the "wedge sum" of $\operatorname{Spf} W(k)$ and $\operatorname{Spf} k[[t]]$...

Comment: ...even for "easy" objects such as surfaces of general type. What you want will be satisfied if you know that $\operatorname{Def}_A$ is smooth over $W(k)$, but that's a very strong assumption to make.

Comment: @PiotrAchinge Thank you! Could you tell me why $\text{Def}_A$ being smooth over $W(k)$ will make that works? I am not very familiar with deformation theory.

Comment: (Formal) smoothness basically means that for a surjection of complete $W(k)$-algebras $R'\to R$, the induced $\operatorname{Def}_A(R')\to \operatorname{Def}_A(R)$ is surjective. Your $B\in \operatorname{Def}_A(k[[t]])$ and $C\in \operatorname{Def}_A(W(k))$ together define a $D_0 \in \operatorname{Def}_A(R)$ where $R = k[[t]]\times_k W(k) = W(k)[[t]]/(pt)$ (look up Schlessinger's criteria). Now use the surjection $R' = W(k)[[t]]\to R$ to get your $D\in \operatorname{Def}_A(W(k)[[t]])$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I have a naive question. Does "$B \in \text{Def}_A k[[t]]$ and $C \in \text{Def}_A W(k)$ together define a $D_0 \in \text{Def}_A(R)$" come from the surjectivity of $\text{Def}_A (U \times_V W) \xrightarrow{}  \text{Def}_A (U) \times_{\text{Def}_A(V)} \text{Def}_A(W)$? I think the criterion only apply to the case when $U,V, W$ are Artinian and $W$ is a small extension of $V$.